# How to use inline assembly to write data with MOVNTI instruction to variable memory address?

Tags: c++, memory, inline-assembly

for a C++ project I'm currently working on I have the following situation:
*adr1* is an address in memory that will be randomly selected from a mapped memory for every run of my program. Now I want to write to this address using the `MOVNTI` (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movnti) instruction. However, I'm pretty new to inline assembly and do not know which constraints and which data-type to use for this.
My current code:

```
asm volatile(
"movntiq %%rax, %[in1] \n"
:
: [in1] "m" (adr1)
);
```

I tried using the "i" and "c" constraints for the input variable but the compiler does not write the assembly code I want to have.
What I want to have written in the end is this (let's say *adr1 = 0x12345678*):

```
movntiq %%rax, 0x12345678
```

However, the compiler currently creates this:

```
movntiq %%rax, -8(%rbp)
```

How do I have to set the constraints and variable type of *adr1* to achieve my goal?

Comment: `What I want ...is ... movntiq %%rax, 0x12345678` - then the address would need to be known at compile-time, no?

Comment: Any reason you're not using the `_mm_stream_si64` intrinsic like a normal person?  Inline asm is almost always worse.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm unless you have a good reason.

Comment: If you want to store to the memory *pointed-to* by `adr1`, rather than to `adr1` itself, use `*adr1` to reference that C/C++ object.  i.e. `"=m"(*adr1)` as an output operand, letting the compiler fill in the addressing mode for it.  That's the point of an `"m"` or `"=m"` constraint.

Comment: Haven't found an exact duplicate about what `"=m"` does, but [Why is this pointer dereference ignored in this inline assembly statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52936681) shows how `"m"` expands, and explains why.

Comment: Update: [GNU C inline asm "m" constraint with a pointer: address vs. pointed-to value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7139305) is an exact duplicate: using the pointer value instead of the pointed-to value.

Comment: IMHO, place your assembly instructions into a separate assembly language file and pass it to the linker.  A lot easier than getting inline assembly working (again, that's just my opinion).

Comment: @PeterCordes I want to use inline assembly because I am working with a lot of write-operations that I don't want the compiler to optimize (research about Rowhammer attack). Thanks for the link, I'll check out the related thread.

Comment: You should try the intrinsic and see if your compiler does dead store elimination on that intrinsic or not.  If you follow it with `asm("" ::: "memory")` for GNU C (a compiler memory barrier), it shouldn't be able to.